# How to resolve initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

I have the following c code:

```
int argv = 2;
char **argv = {"test arg 1",
          "test arg 2"};
```

When I compile it, I get teh following warning:

warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Can you please tell me what's wrong for my initialization?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't you mean `int argc = 2;`?

Comment: you should probably get these from the command line, not inside the program. argv is usually filled with the name of the program followed by the rest of the command line arguments. then again, your program might be named "test arg 1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char **` is a pointer type not an array type.

Use an array type:

```
char *argv[] = {"test arg 1", "test arg 2"};
```